# Showing inheritance in a UML class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, staruml

Here is a simple inheritance in UML :

[image]

I used to believe it was possible, with UML, to represent it in a "shorter" version, like this :

[image]

But the CASE tool I'm using right now does not allow me to use the latter. I checked the internet and various books I own and as I didn't find anything about it, I started to wonder if the "shorter" version is correct regarding the UML spécifications.

Answer (score 3):

This has and is being used in Enterprise Architect. I searched in older UML specs but could not find any trace. The current UML 2.5 does not define that notation.

---

I think that it's a useful notation and asked Sparx to bring it on the agenda of OMG. But even if it does, OMG is very, very slow.